# Execute code after firebase upload process completed

Tags: javascript, firebase

I don't understand why does my files didn't uploaded, looks like the upload process terminated by the next code.

Is there any way to execute the second block after the upload process completed?

here's my code

```
 upload() {
      //First Block
      this.loading = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.imageCount; i++) {
          this.uploadFile(this.imageData[i]);
        }
      ////


      //Second Block
        this.loading = false;
        this.reset();
        alert("Upload Success");
      ///


    },


 reset() {
      this.previewImages = [];
      this.imageCount = 0;
      this.urls = [];
      this.imageData = [];
      const input = this.$refs.fileInput;
      input.type = "text";
      input.type = "file";
    }

   uploadFile(file) {
      this.picture = null;
      const storageRef = firebase
        .storage()
        .ref(`images/products/${file.name}`)
        .put(file);
      storageRef.on(
        `state_changed`,
        () => {
          this.uploadValue += 100 / this.imageCount;
          storageRef.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
            this.urls.push(url);

          });
        }
      );
    },
```

I didn't call any API method yet, but my idea is to store all of the urls and then send them to API at the end. I'm also looking the right way to do that.

Comment: if you show us the `uploadFile` function, we might be able to help you. Hopefully it returns a Promise, or provides a callback which you can run when it completes.

Comment: I've added the uploadFile function

Comment: Ok so looks like you need to wait for the `state_changed` event before you run any further code. However, you appear to be potentially uploading multiple files, all asynchronously, which makes it trickier to wait until they're all done. I suggest creating a Promise inside the uploadFile function, and making the promise resolve inside the "state_changed" callback. Return the Promise from your uploadFile() function. Then use Promise.all in the upload() function with all the promises returned from the calls to uploadFile(), so you can see when all the files have completed.

Comment: There's pretty much an exact replica of your question, and a working answer, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809980/javascript-loop-doesnt-wait-for-firebase-to-complete-uploading-multiple-files